# Using @Value Spring Annotation with Groovy

Tags: spring, groovy, annotations, properties

I have a groovy class where I wan to autowire a property value.

Eg:

```
public @Value("${valueA}" ) String valueA;
```

With the addition of the the property-placeholder in my appliction context

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/app.properties" />
```

The app.properties has a value set for  "valueA" so in theory this should populate the String valueA in my class at runtime.

This setup works perfectly if I use a java class but not if I use a groovy class.

I get a compile error:

> Error: expected '$valueA' to be an inline constant of type java.lang.String in @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
>   Error: Attribute 'value' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value

I just want to know if the above syntax is correct when using a groovy class and if not what is the correct syntax for autowiring the @Value parameter at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. It was driving me sort of crazy but the answers below do the trick.

Answer (score 86):

Use single quotes, ie.

```
public @Value('${valueA}') String valueA
```

Comment: Is this because with double quotes you get a GString instead of a String and the substitution is done at the wrong time?

Comment: Thanks, this affected me in my Groovy project. I suspect this doesn't happen in Java as there is no GString type.

Comment: This seems to work, but not when attempting to use a default value.  `public @Value('${propertyName:defaultValue}') String valueA`  In this scenario, 'defaultValue' is **always** used as the value for _propertyName_, even when overridden in a property file.  The value in the property file is not used.

Answer (score 33):

since using a $ causes Groovy to interpret the annotation argument as a GString, you get a compile error. you can either escape \$ or use single quotes.