# How to inject property values into a Spock test?

Tags: spring, groovy, dependency-injection, spock

When using a Spock test, i have hardcoded some properties hardcoded into the spock test. The example is a JDBC url. I tried the @Value annotation together with a propertie file, but this seems not to work as my test has no stereotype. Are there any other solutions to inject property values?

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:applicationContext-test.xml")
class RepositoryTest extends Specification {

    @Shared sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver:// - room - for - properties")    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shared properties cannot be injected, but something like this should work (with Spring 3):

```
@Value("#{databaseProperties.jdbcUrl}")
String jdbcUrl

Sql sql

def setup() {
  if (!sql) {
    sql = new Sql(jdbcUrl)
  }
}
```

This assumes that you have defined "databaseProperties" in your bean definition file:

```
<util:properties id="databaseProperties" location="classpath:database.properties" />
```

Comment: Earlier on i tried to do more or less the same with a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, but i could not get this to work together with the @Value annotation. 

Your way of using the util:properties works perfect!

Comment: Is it also possible to use the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer for this?

Answer (score 4):

To use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, add a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728000/value-not-resolved-when-using-propertysource-annotation-how-to-configure-prop).

And then, in Spock:

```
@Value('${foo.bar}') //Use single quote.
String fooBar
```

The reason to use single quote is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648398/using-value-spring-annotation-with-groovy).

And you probably need to add `@ContextConfiguration` to your Spock class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DatabaseConfig .class)
class Test extends Specification {
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is more helpful

Answer (score 0):

use jvm system properties "java -DdbUsername=bbbb"