# How to use the @Value annotation with a Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in a Spock test?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations, spock

It is possible to use the @Value annotation with a Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

> ```
> <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
>       p:location="classpath:application-test.properties"
> />
> ```

The `<util:properties id="appProperties" location="classpath:application-test.properties" />` works correct with @Value but i would like to use 1 way of configuring. Now i have the both of them pointing towards the same property file.

Comment: Hmm, I should have posted my solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41884089/5290465) here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer if you have already setup util:properties.  In your bean config, create the util:properties bean and then within your classes annotate like

```
@Value("#{myProps.someProperty}")
```

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?69602-Value-and-PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Comment: But is it possible to use only PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer? I need that to replace stuff in my applicationContext.xml, so i need the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer.