# @Value not resolved when using @PropertySource annotation. How to configure PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: spring, configuration

I have following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name = "props", value = "classpath:/app-config.properties")
@ComponentScan("service")
public class AppConfig {
```

and I have service with property:

```
@Component 
public class SomeService {
    @Value("#{props['some.property']}") private String someProperty;
```

I receive error when I want to test the AppConfig configuration class with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String service.SomeService.someProperty; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'props' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

The issue is documented [in SPR-8539](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8539)

but anyway I cannot figure out how to configure **PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer**  to get it work.

### Edit 1

This approach works well with xml configuration

```
<util:properties id="props" location="classpath:/app-config.properties" />
```

but I want to use java for configuration.

Comment: done :) I didn't investigate more but mentioned ticked was marked as "won't fix"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you use @PropertySource, properties have to be retrieved with:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
// ...
String subject = env.getProperty("mail.subject");
```

If you want to retrieve with `@Value("${mail.subject}")`, you have to register the prop placeholder by xml.

Reason:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8539

Comment: You can also add the static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean in java to allow for the @Value to work.. Here is a sample

    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        configurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        return configurer;
    }

Answer (score 138):

as @cwash said;

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/test-config.properties")
public class TestConfig {

     @Value("${name}")
     public String name;


     //You need this
     @Bean
     public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
     }

}
```

Comment: This is also the way suggested in the java docs. See "Using the @Value annotation" in https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: This works perfectly, we do not need to use xml config files. Just PropertySource annotation and declaring the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with Bean annotation is enough.

Comment: I just put `@Component` on my custom implementation of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and it registered fine without needing to declare a dedicated bean

Answer (score 16):

I found the reason `@value` was not working for me is, `@value` requires `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. I did the same changes and it worked for me, I am using spring 4.0.3 release. I configured this using below code in my configuration file.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
   return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Comment: I am using Spring 4.3.10 and "@value" is working with "@PropertySource". I didn't configure PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean

Comment: Confirmed, Spring 4.3.10 no needs PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

Answer (score 13):

Don't you need a method on your @Configuration class that returns PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, annotated @Bean and is static, to register any @PropertySource with Spring?

http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/#java

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8539

Answer (score 6):

I had the very same problem. `@PropertySource` is not playing well with `@Value`. A quick workaround is to have an XML configuration which you'll refer to it from your Spring Java Configuration using `@ImportResource` as usual and that XML configuration file will include a single entry: `<context:property-placeholder />` (of course with the needed namespace ceremony). Without any other change `@Value` will inject properties in your `@Configuration` pojo.

Answer (score 5):

This can also be configured in java this way

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    configurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    return configurer;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That looks mighty complicated, can't you just do

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:some.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

then in code reference:

```
@Value("${myProperty}")
private String myString;

@Value("${myProperty.two}")
private String myStringTwo;
```

where some.properties looks something like this

```
myProperty = whatever
myProperty.two = something else\
that consists of multiline string
```

For java based config you can do this

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:some.properties")
public class SomeService {
```

And then just inject using `@value` as before

Comment: No properties are in text file: `@PropertySource(name = "props", value = "classpath:/app-config.properties")` I just want to replace .xml with java config which is available in Spring 3

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem. As I said it works with spring xml configuration. But I need solution for Java config with Value annotation as I wrote. I'm not looking for alternative solution.

Comment: I don't think I should annotate service with _@Configuration_. I tried to move **@PropertySource** directly to service but the error is the same

Comment: @coffy I'm looking for the exactly same thing.  Do you remember what the solution was to this?

Comment: @matus, nope, it doesn't work like that (Spring 4.3.1).

Answer (score 3):

Since Spring 4.3 RC2 using `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` or `<context:property-placeholder>` is not needed anymore. We can use directly `@PropertySource` with `@Value`. See this [Spring framework ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14140)

I have created a test application with Spring 5.1.3.RELEASE.
The `application.properties` contains two pairs:

```
app.name=My application
app.version=1.1
```

The `AppConfig` loads the properties via `@PropertySource`.

```
package com.zetcode.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class AppConfig {

}
```

The `Application` injects the properties via `@Value` and uses them.

```
package com.zetcode;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.zetcode")
public class Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Value("${app.name}")
    private String appName;

    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String appVersion;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        var app = ctx.getBean(Application.class);

        app.run();

        ctx.close();
    }

    public void run() {

        logger.info("Application name: {}", appName);
        logger.info("Application version: {}", appVersion);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
$ mvn -q exec:java
22:20:10.894 [com.zetcode.Application.main()] INFO  com.zetcode.Application - Application name: My application
22:20:10.894 [com.zetcode.Application.main()] INFO  com.zetcode.Application - Application version: 1.1
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is: as far as I get it, <util:propertes id="id" location="loc"/>, is just a shorthand for

```
<bean id="id" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location" value="loc"/>
</bean>
```

(see [documentation of util:properties](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties)). Thus, when you use util:properties, a standalone bean is created.

@PropertySource, on the other hand, as documentation says is an

> annotation providing a convenient and declarative mechanism for
>   adding a PropertySource to Spring's Environment'.

(see [@PropertySource doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)). So it doesn't create any bean.

Then "#{a['something']}" is a SpEL expression (see [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)), that means "get something from **bean** 'a'". When util:properties is used, the bean exists and the expression is meaningful, but when @PropertySource is used, there is no actual bean and the expression is meaningless.

You can workaround this either by using XML (which is the best way, I think) or by issuing a PropertiesFactoryBean by yourself, declaring it as a normal @Bean.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that may be happening: ensure your @Value annotated values are not static.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, depends-on="bean1" was within property-placeholder was causing the issue. I removed that dependency and used @PostConstruct to achieve the same original functionality and was able to read the new values too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring with xml, after adding

> <context:property-placeholder location="..."/>

Make sure your annotations are activated. In my case properties were not fetched for this reason:

> <context:annotation-config/>

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked

spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:///Users/${your username}/Projects/git-local-repositories/
spring.profiles.active=native