# Spring JavaConfig properties in bean is not getting set?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am looking at using Spring JavaConfig  with some property files but properties in bean is not getting set?in bean is not getting set?

Here is my WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@Import(DatabaseConfig.class)
@ImportResource("/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String MESSAGE_SOURCE = "/WEB-INF/classes/messages";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebMVCConfig.class);

    @Value("${rt.setPassword}")
    private String RTPassword;

    @Value("${rt.setUrl}")
    private String RTURL;

    @Value("${rt.setUser}")
    private String RTUser;


    @Bean
    public  ViewResolver resolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver url = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        url.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        url.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        url.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return url;
    }


    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource configureMessageSource() {
        logger.debug("setting up message source");
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename(MESSAGE_SOURCE);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver lr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        lr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return lr;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        logger.debug("setting up resource handlers");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/").addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        logger.debug("configureDefaultServletHandling");
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver b = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        mappings.put("org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound", "p404");
        mappings.put("org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException", "dataAccessFailure");
        mappings.put("org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException", "dataAccessFailure");
        b.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
        return b;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestTrackerConfig requestTrackerConfig()
    {
        RequestTrackerConfig tr = new RequestTrackerConfig();
        tr.setPassword(RTPassword);
        tr.setUrl(RTURL);
        tr.setUser(RTUser);

        return tr;
    }


}
```

**The value in tr.url is "rt.setUrl" not the value in application.properties?**

Comment: the `@Override public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)` method have wrong implementation. Correct implementation is `registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100%, but I think your `@PropertySource` isn't quite right. Instead of

`@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")`

It should just be:

`@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`

based on this:

[Spring PropertySource Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

Also, based on the link above and since you have mentioned you were converting to a java config approach instead of xml, I think the below might be the solution to your issue:

> Resolving ${...} placeholders in  and @Value annotations In
>   order to resolve ${...} placeholders in  definitions or @Value
>   annotations using properties from a PropertySource, one must register
>   a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. This happens automatically
>   when using  in XML, but must be
>   explicitly registered using a static @Bean method when using
>   @Configuration classes. See the "Working with externalized values"
>   section of @Configuration Javadoc and "a note on
>   BeanFactoryPostProcessor-returning @Bean methods" of @Bean Javadoc for
>   details and examples.

The example from the link above is how I normally do it:

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
 public class AppConfig {
     @Autowired
     Environment env;

     @Bean
     public TestBean testBean() {
         TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
         testBean.setName(env.getProperty("testbean.name"));
         return testBean;
    }
 }
```

So add at the top:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

Then in your method use:

```
tr.setPassword(env.getProperty("rt.setPassword"));
```

and so on for the remaining property values.  I am just not as familiar with the way you are doing it.  I know the above approach will work though.

Comment: i changed it and it did NOT help :(

Comment: I think that last thing I just posted might be your solution.  Since you just converted to java config instead of xml configuration.  Did you add that `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to your config?

Comment: I think I found the issue in my properties file the password is rt.setPassword=Waiting#$\ and its not letting the next line work

Comment: but I dont know how to make it work with the password value of Waiting#$\

Comment: This should get you started on figuring out how to escape the characters you need to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406975/how-to-escape-the-equals-sign-in-properties-files

Comment: The claim you made at eh begining of your answer is not correct. `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")` and `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` are essentially the same exact thing, since the value attribute of an annotation is populated by default if no attribute name is passed into the annotation declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from @ssn771 answer that involves injecting the `Environment` and retrieving the properties through it which is indeed the suggested way of doing it, [this is what I've done as a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16772991/185723) without having to change the way `@Value` is being used in the `@Configuration` POJO.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the many suggested things the most important one is that you need to configure `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in Spring 3.1+ (or `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in Spring 3.0). It must be `static` if you want it to be applied to the configuration class (to use `@Value` annotations).

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

From javadoc for PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer :

> This class is designed as a general replacement for PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring 3.1 applications. It is used by default to support the property-placeholder element in working against the spring-context-3.1 XSD, whereas spring-context versions <= 3.0 default to PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to ensure backward compatibility. See the spring-context XSD documentation for complete details.