# Can't pull values from .properties file using annotations

Tags: java, spring

I want to configure my bean String fields through .proprerties file. But it doesn't replace the value key, means it echo "${value}" string. My code below:

*Main class:*

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        ValuesContainer valuesContainer = (ValuesContainer) applicationContext.getBean("container");
        System.out.println(valuesContainer.getValue()); //echoes "${value}" instead of Ho-ho-ho!
    }
}
```

*application context:*

```
.....
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="bean"/>
```

*bean:*

```
package bean;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("container")
@Scope("singleton")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:app.properties")
public class ValuesContainer {

    @Value("${value}")
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

*app.properties:*

```
value = Ho-ho-ho!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in your configuration.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728000/value-not-resolved-when-using-propertysource-annotation-how-to-configure-prop).

Answer (score 2):

`@PropertySource` should be used with `@Configuration`.

You need to create a separate `@Configuration` class, put your annotation `@PropertySource` on it and add it to your application context (or let `<context:component-scan>` to add it).

Alternatively you can configure property sources of your application context programmatically, [using `Environment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#getEnvironment%28%29).