# How to inject value in annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have application.properties file. I load this file using

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

and now I want to inject a property it to annotation value, in my case

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "")
```

I've tried following without success.

```
"#{${cors.origins}}"
```

Note: cors.origins is field I want to inject.

Comment: Duplicate. Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259302/cant-pull-values-from-properties-file-using-annotations

Comment: Standard @Value annotation works just fine. There is no problem with loading specified property, but rather with injecting it into annotation itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime/14276270#14276270