# Is there a way to include properties file in another properties file?

Tags: spring, properties, spring-boot

I'd like to avoid cluttering the `application.properties` file with lots of things than, in my opinion, would be better in a separate file.

`application.properties` should be something like

```
@include module1.properties
@include module1.properties
...
###################################
######### Spring Misc #############
###################################

# Direct log to a log file
logging.file=/tmp/kmp-manager.log

#local listening port
server.port=8082

spring.profiles=nr_dev nr_testing production
spring.profiles.active=production

spring.datasource.platform=postgresql

java.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

Is this at all possibile?
If not, what would be a sane way to avoid cluttering?

Comment: Looks like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855795/spring-boot-and-multiple-external-configuration-files). Not importing but loading multiple files - does that answer your question?

Comment: Also, consider using [YAML](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml) rather than `properties` - this gives a much more structured document.

Answer (score 17):

Spring Boot Spring Boot 2.4 has added a feature for importing

We can now use `spring.config.import=developer.properties` to import other file. Check this [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4) post for more details

Answer (score 4):

It's possible in `YML` file and the configuration are very simple

*EXAMPLE:*

To include properties of `application-DATABASE.yml` file in `application.yml`, use

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: DATABASE
```

[EDIT - for 2.4.0 and above]

`spring.profiles.group.prod=DATABASE`

OR

Add the file name in `application.properties`

```
spring.config.import=classpath:application-DEV.yml,classpath:application-UDEV.yml,classpath:application-PRO.yml,classpath:application-SBA.yml
```

Comment: This seems to be possible in Spring Boot 2.4 now: https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4#importing-additional-configuration

Answer (score 2):

```
spring.config.import: file:${CLOUDJAVA_ROOT}/config/application.yaml
```

Imports are processed as they are discovered, and are treated as additional documents inserted immediately below the one that declares the import. Values from the imported file will take precedence over the file that triggered the import.

See spring-boot docs: [Importing Additional Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.importing)