# How to force library class to use your bean in autowiring

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have encountered a scenario in my application where I am calling a library class method which uses autowiring with `@Qualifier` annotation. In my case, the behavior is exact same but the autowired bean should be different. This autowired bean simply calls a REST service.

I have tried to show the scenario with few simple classes:

```
public interface IMessage {
    public String getMessage();
}

public class HelloMessage implements IMessage {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public class HiMessage implements IMessage  {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hi";
    }
}

public class PrintMessage { 
    @Qualifier("helloMessage")
    @Autowired
    private IMessage message;

    public void service() {
        System.out.println(message.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Suppose all these classes belong to library. The only thing I am trying to achieve is `HiMessage` bean to be autowired in `PrintMessage` class. Overriding this class would be simple solution but since the `service()` method behavior is exact same so I don't want to override it just for using different autowired bean.

Comment: Whatever bean you create name it `helloMessage`.

Comment: answer would be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830548/spring-autowired-and-qualifier

Comment: @M.Deinum How can you declare two beans with same id? Alias option is there but that would also require redefining the behavior in a different bean.

Comment: Why would you need to change the behavior? When creating a bean with the same name it will override the other one, hence the `HiMessage` bean is availabel and will be injected.

Answer (score 1):

In your `@Configuration` class, create a `@Bean("helloMessage")`-annotated method which just returns the desired bean:

```
@Bean("helloMessage)"
public IMessage republishHiMessage() {
    return new HiMessage();
}
```

or by using parameter injection, if your desired object is already known as `hiMessage`:

```
@Bean("helloMessage)"
public IMessage republishHiMessage(@Qualifier("hiMessage") IMessage hiMessage) {
    return hiMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example in following case it is necessary provide a qualifer.

```
@Component
@Qualifier("helloMessage")
public class HelloMessage implements IMessage {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Hope this will be help for you. cheers!