# Injecting spring bean among two beans- implementing same interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, dependency-injection

I have two spring bean classes which are implemeting the same interface.

```
 public interface Abc()
  {
    String getNumber();
  }
```

The two classes are

```
 @Service
 public class SomeClass implements abc
  {

  @Override
  public class getNumber()
  {


  }

 }


 @Service
 public class SomeClass1 implements abc
 {

  @Override
  public class getNumber()
  {

  }
  }
```

In my Service class.

```
 @Service
 public class Demo
  {

  @Autowired
  private Abc abc;

  }

  }
```

I got an error "required a single bean, but 2 were found"

For that error i can have the chance to put @Primary in the top of one of the bean.

But i have only way to say "one bean configuration" based on the value which i will get in runtime(From the database).

Can you please suggest me a way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830548/spring-autowired-and-qualifier

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but there's a `@Qualifier` annotation for dealing with multiple spring bean implementations.

Comment: The question is unclear about what you want want. However, if you are looking for to have beans based on external property then you can use @ConditionalOnProperty. Check more on Spring Docs for use case.

Answer (score 6):

You can autowire a list of interfaces and then choose the right one. You can write:

```
@Autowired
List<Abc> abcs;
```

this will result in a list of implementations of the interface. In your method body you can then choose the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of ways you can autowire the correct implementation.

Change your autowired field name to the same name of the implementation class (in camelcase)

```
@Autowired
private Abc someClass;
```

This will attempt to find an implementation of interface 'Abc' with the classname 'SomeClass'.

Another way is to add a bean name to your service annotation

```
@Service("someClass")
public class SomeClass implements abc
```

This can then be autowired like the following

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("someClass")
private Abc SomeClass;
```

Comment: Are you sure sping autowires interfaces the way you described in the first option? What if a have SomeClass1 and SomeClass2?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem he is asking about how to configure two implentation and also using the right bean dynamically(based on data in DB) . It seems this is the an example for factory pattern

Psuedo Code

```
Class SomeFactory{
 @Autowired
 private Abc someClass;
  @Autowired
  private Abc someClass1;// keeping bean Name same as class name would solve bean finding issue

public Abc getBeanFor(String type) {
if("someClass".equals(type)
    return someClass;
  return someClass1;
} 
}

Class TestClass{
 @Autowired
   private SomeFactory factory ;
  private void someProcess() {
   // Read type from DB for data

   factory.getBeanFor(typeReadFromData)
                .process();
 } 
}
```