# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: Don't Control Bean Creation Class

Tags: java, spring

In Spring, is it possible to avoid a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` in the following scenario:

- My application references beans in a 3rd party library

  ```
   appBean="thirdPartyClass"
  ```
- The bean code is in a 3rd party library I can't edit

  ```
   @Component
   public class ThirdPartyClass {

       @Autowired
       private ThirdPartyInterface thirdPartyInterface;
  ```
- The third party interface is used by two classes I do control

This class:

```
  public class MyClass1 implements ThirdPartyInterface {
```

and this class:

```
   public class MyClass2 implements ThirdPartyInterface {
```

Currently, `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` is occurring when I try to start my application saying the following:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'thirdPartyClass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'thirdPartyIntereface'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ThirdPartyInterface' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: MyClass1,MyClass2`

Comment: Why are you creating two beans for that interface?

Comment: They are two different queue listeners. The third party interface is for a queue listener.

Comment: Given that `ThirdPartyClass` requires a single queue listener, why are you creating two queue listeners? It seems that `ThirdPartyClass` will only use one.

Comment: The listeners are for two different queues. I'm setting different queue names to listen to.

Answer (score 2):

> Considering you cannot change the `ThirdPartyClass` class.

Make one of the implemented classes as `@Primary` to be considered as the **primary bean** to be `Autowired` in the `ThirdPartyClass` class.

```java
@Primary
@Component
public class MyClass1 implements ThirdPartyInterface {
}
```

And add `@Qualifier` to the other implemented class. And use that same qualifier in your other classes to `Autowire` and use it seamlessly.

```java
@Component
@Qualifier("queue2")
public class MyClass2 implements ThirdPartyInterface {
}

@Component
public class MyOtherClass {
     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("queue2")
     private ThirdPartyInterface thirdPartyInterface;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says what the problem is -

When you have 2 class implementing same interface and you are trying to use `@Autowired` via the interface, Spring does not know which implementation to pick (`MyClass1` or `MyClass2`).

You need to be specific. Use `@Qualifier` to specify which implementation to pick.

I quickly found one example here - [Spring @Autowired and @Qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830548/spring-autowired-and-qualifier)

Comment: I can't change the third party class where the @Autowired is.

Comment: @user7340 Then you can use the approach that @sas suggested. You will have to create another version of `ThirdPartyClass` to use other implementation. Else, only Primary will be picked.