# @Qualifier field versus constructor parameters injection problems in Spring

Tags: java, regex, spring, validation, constructor-injection

I have two beans: `CheckPassword` and `CheckEmail`

```java
@Service("CheckPassword")
@Primary
public class CheckPassword implements CheckStringInterface {

    private static final String regex_password = "^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&+=!])(?=\\S+$).{8,20}$";

    @Override
    public boolean isStringValid(String rawPassword) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex_password);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rawPassword);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

```java
@Service("CheckEmail")
public class CheckEmail implements CheckStringInterface {

    private static final String regex_password = "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$";

    @Override
    public boolean isStringValid(String rawPassword) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex_password);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rawPassword);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

I use `@Qualifier` to select the bean I need, but why is it that only password returns `true` while email always returns `false`?

```java
@Qualifier("CheckPassword")
private final CheckStringInterface checkPasswordFormat;

@Qualifier("CheckEmail")
private final CheckStringInterface checkEmailFormat;

@Qualifier("EmailVerifyCode")
private final VerificationCodeManager verificationCodeManager;

@Value("${email_root}")
private String email_root;

private final SendMailTemplateService sendMailTemplateService;

private static final String template_verify_code_register = "templateVerifyCodeRegister";
private static String message_notification = "Use the code to verify this email: ";

@Transactional 
public Integer register(RegisterDTO registerDTO, HttpServletRequest request){
    if (userService.findByEmail(registerDTO.email()) == null) {
        if (checkPasswordFormat.isStringValid(registerDTO.password()) == false
        || checkEmailFormat.isStringValid(registerDTO.email()) == false) {
            log.info("Wrong Format {}", checkPasswordFormat.isStringValid(registerDTO.password()));
            log.info("Wrong Format {}", checkEmailFormat.isStringValid(registerDTO.email()));
           return 0; // Wrong format email or password
        }

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(registerDTO.email());
        user.setFullName(registerDTO.fullName());
        user.setPassword(registerDTO.password());
        user.setCreatedAt(Time.getTheTimeRightNow());
        user.setUserVerifyCode(verificationCodeManager.generateCode());
        user.setUserVerifyCodeExpirationTime(verificationCodeManager.codeExpiration());
        log.info("------> RegisterService | register: register with email {}", user.getEmail());
        createUser.create(user);
        sendMail(user, user.getUserVerifyCode());

        request.getSession().setAttribute("email", registerDTO.email());
        return 1; // Create successful
    } else {
        return 2; // Email already exists
    }
}
```

This is the data I use to test the API on Swagger:

```json
{
  "email": "bonbon147852369@gmail.com",
  "fullName": "abcdABCD",
  "password": "Password@1234"
}
```

I tried to change to another regex but it didn't help.
When I log it I see password always return `true` because I input the right format but email will return `false` with both right and wrong format.

Comment: please add the constructor injection code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted in the question doesn't work for two main reasons:

1. The regex validation for the email is wrong
2. The injection of beans `CheckPassword` and `CheckEmail` is made in a wrong way

---

#### REGEX PROBLEM:

I see two main problems in your regex email validation:

1. You only included uppercase letters in your regex for the email (which will cause all strings containing undercase letters to fail)
2. You used `\\\\` before the `.` character, which will make the regex expect a `\` (because to write the backslash in java you need `\\` so another two `\\` will actually escape it) and will cause the dot to be interpreted as special character meaning "any character"

With your current setup,

- `isStringValid("BONBON147852369@GMAIL\\.COM")` returns `true`
- `isStringValid("BONBON147852369@GMAIL\\ACOM")` returns `true`
- `isStringValid("bONBON147852369@GMAIL\\.COM")` returns `false`

To fix your code, you need to use only two backslashes (instead of 4) before the dot, so that you will escape the dot character and you also need to make your regex expect also undercase letters:

```java
@Service("CheckEmail")
public class CheckEmail implements CheckStringInterface {
    private static final String regex_email = "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$";
    @Override
    public boolean isStringValid(String rawEmail) {
        // alternative to Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE is to include a-z interval in your regex
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex_email, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rawEmail);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

---

#### BEAN INJECTION PROBLEM:

The OP used constructor injection, but put `@Qualifier` on fields declarations. This caused the annotation to be ignored and hence only the bean with `@Primary` annotation was picked (the `CheckPassword` one).
To solve the problem, you can either

- Use field injection by putting BOTH `@Qualifier` and `@Autowired` on fields' declarations (but that is not a best practice)
- Fix your constructor injection by properly using `@Qualifier` (see the first answer here: [Spring @Autowired and @Qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830548/spring-autowired-and-qualifier))

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I followed it but it still doesn't work. I tried logging 2 Beans CheckPassword and CheckEmail but somehow it only uses CheckPassword's Bean for both email and password from the data I enter. without using the CheckEmail bean

Comment: @HiếuĐỗ there is some problem with autowiring then. I don't see the `@Autowired` annotation on top of your `@Qualifier("CheckPassword")` and `@Qualifier("CheckEmail")`. Are you using constructor injection or field injection?

Comment: I am using constructor injection and after i tried  `@Qualifier` doesn't work with constructor injection so i think i need to add `@Autowired` for field injection and it work normally, thank for your anwser

Answer (score 0):

## XY Problem

Based on the OP's comment:

> Thank u, but i think i found what i was wrong. I user `@Qualifier` to find a bean i want to use but i didn't use it with `@Autowired`, I use it with constructor injection so it doesn't work after i add `@Autowired` it work right way

I deduce that the problem was actually that they used a constructor injection as they should, but they don't understand how the `@Qualifier` works, so **the `CheckPassword` bean was injected twice!!!**. Both `checkPasswordFormat` and `checkEmailFormat` were of type `CheckPassword` in runtime, which explains why the code wasn't run, obviously!

OP decided to use `@Autowired` field injection, which is not recommended, the use of constructor is better here. OP should move the qualifier annotations to the constructor instead:

```java
public class SendEmailManager {
    public SendEmailManager(@Qualifier("CheckPassword") CheckStringInterface checkPasswordFormat, 
        @Qualifier("CheckEmail") CheckStringInterface checkEmailFormat) {
    this.checkPasswordFormat = checkPasswordFormat;
    this.checkEmailFormat = checkEmailFormat;
}
```

## Java operator behavior, answer to the OP's comment

You wrote in a comment:

> Thank you for your answer but I followed it but it still doesn't work. I tried logging 2 Beans CheckPassword and CheckEmail but somehow it only uses CheckPassword's Bean for both email and password from the data I enter. without using the CheckEmail bean

Look at your code

```java
checkPasswordFormat.isStringValid(registerDTO.password()) == false
    || checkEmailFormat.isStringValid(registerDTO.email()) == false
```

[If the first operand of the Conditional-OR (`||`) operator evaluates to `true`, the other operand is not evaluated at all, so the code instruction inside of the second clause won't run.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

The Oracle tutorial doesn't explain it super clear, but read

> The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR operations on two boolean expressions. **These operators exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is evaluated only if needed**.

So, in your example the first clause `checkPasswordFormat.isStringValid(registerDTO.password()) == false` evaluates to `true`, so the second clause does not need to be evaluated, so the `checkEmailFormat.isStringValid` method doesn't run at all, as it should be.

Comment: Thank u, but i think i found what i was wrong. I user `@Qualifier` to find a bean i want to use but i didn't use it with `@Autowired`, I use it with constructor injection so it doesn't work after i add `@Autowired` it work right way

Comment: @banan3'14 even if the code is not so readable, the logic is correct. If either the password or mail validation fails (the isStringValid returns false) you don't need to evaluate the other condition, because you don't register a user even if only one of the validations doesn't pass

Comment: @pochopsp that wasn't the point. The point was that OP didn't seem to understand how the operator works judging from their comment.

Comment: @HiếuĐỗ Oh now I see what's wrong. You used `@Qualifier` on fields instead of constructor parameters. I will update the answer.