# Spring boot overriding property in other application files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running my jar in the following way in unix

java -jar $classpath --spring.config.location=application.yml

And I am also using a properties file which I am configuring the following way:

```
@PropertySource("file:${DATASERVICE_PROPERTIES}")
```

Both application.yml and DATASERVICE_PROPERTIES have property

```
server.port
```

I want to use the server.port in application.yml.

I thought properties supplied via commandline has highest precedence(from below link), so why is server.port from DATASERVICE_PROPERTIES taken?

[Spring Boot and multiple external configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855795/spring-boot-and-multiple-external-configuration-files)

Answer (score 0):

Properties supplied via command line override properties in `src/main/resources/application.properties` and in `config/application.properties`
Since you are specifying in the code the file to use this doesn't apply. 
Why aren't you using on of the two property file location above ? 
So you can remove your @PropertySource and your will be able to override your properties via command line .

Comment: because the config files cant be there, they are deployed in a separate location.