# spring.config.location - properties overloading with multiple files

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I'm trying to configure my Spring application.

I have in `/src/main/resources` my file `application.yml`. In my main class there is no `@PropertySource` annotation (but I tried also using that).

I also have another file on my Windows (`/c/Programs/application.yml`) that has similar content (some values are overriden).

I have to run application with following cmd call (my organization doesn't want me to use another call, because it part of CI/CD standard process):

```
java -Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,/c/Programs/application.yml -jar app.jar
```

My `/src/main/resurces/application.yml` file is included with `.jar` after building app. Running app with cmd above uses keys from `resources`, not from second file.

As I gathered from few hours of trying to solve this:

1. with two files `spring.config.location`, second one overrides values from first one,
2. files should be separated by comma,
3. I don't have to use `spring.config.name`, when I specify single file (not directory).

What is the problem with my configuration? How can I override file from resources with external file?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855795/spring-boot-and-multiple-external-configuration-files

Comment: @user7294900 Thank you - I found there information about multiple files, but I wasn't able to use it in my project.

Comment: Try `java -Dspring.config.location=classpath/application.yml,file:c/Programs/application.yml`

Comment: It still uses `classpath:/application.yml`, as default properties file.

Comment: Use `spring.config.additional-location=file:/c:/programs/` Spring Boot will load an `application.yml` from that location automatically.

Comment: @M.Deinum But my organization won't allow me to change `java -jar` call. I'm looking for ways to prepare my project to work with that call (if that's posiible)

Comment: You can but you shouldn't. As you will loose the benefit of using profile based loading it will then only load those 2 files and nothing profile specific anymore. I strongly suggest to follow the best practices as laid out in the spring boot reference guide.