# Spring: Configuring the location of message files containing internationalization keys

Tags: spring

I know that by default a Spring application will look for message files containing internationalization keys and values in the `src/main/resources` folder.  What is the best way to specify an alternate location for these message files (i.e. other than `src/main/resources`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot and multiple external configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855795/spring-boot-and-multiple-external-configuration-files)

Answer (score 0):

The more simple way to achieve this is to use in your properties file: `spring.messages.basename`,

There is another more complicated way is to define your own Bean of type: `MessageSource`.
Of course, the first way should be the one to use.

---