# Spring boot external properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to run a java8 app using spring boot version 2.2.4. The app is then packed in a docker image.

The way I run my app as specified in a Dockerfile which ends liek this:

```
FROM openjdk:8
.....
CMD /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java -jar -Dspring.config.location=/opt/$APP/ /opt/$APP/$APP.jar
```

The problem I encounter is the loading of external properties files. 
For example I have application.properties file similar to this, which is **packaed inside the JAR**:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=db1
application.queue.sqs.queue_name=somesqs
```

In addition, I also inject the docker image an addition `application.properties` file located at `/opt/myapp/`. This **external file** is similar to this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://username:password@MONGO_URL:27017/db_name
application.queue.sqs.queue_name=another_sqs
```

**Expected Behavior**: the app will load both new `another_sqs` location, and external mongo connection.

However, **Actual Behavior**: when reading the logs I can see that t the new sqs url (i.e. another_sqs) **is loaded** properly, although the new value for mongo connection is discarded and is therefore using the local embedded mongo engine.

I consulted the following post on stackoverflow to try and understand what I am experiencing:

> [Spring Boot and multiple external configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855795/spring-boot-and-multiple-external-configuration-files)

But for my understanding, when using spring 2.X and above, the -Dspring.config.location should override all other properties file.

**Here is where I started debugging:**

TRY 1 : I attached into the docker container, cd into `/opt/$APP/` where both my `app.jar` and `application.properties` are located, executed the following command `java -jar app.jar` and viola - **it works**! A connection to the external mongo source is established. This may be explained by the priority of spring loading properties files as specified in spring's [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).

TRY 2 : Attach the container, cd into `$HOME/`, execute `java -jar /opt/$APP/app.jar -Dspring.config.location=/opt/$APP/` - Do not connect to external mongo, however does connects to the `another_sqs`. Strange thing - only part of the `application.properties` values are loaded? Isn't it the way spring 1.X works by adding value from multiple files?

TRY 3 : Attach the container, cd into `$HOME/`, execute `java -jar /opt/$APP/app.jar -Dspring.config.location=file:/opt/$APP/applicartion.properties` - same behavior.

Try 4: Edited Dockerfile to include the following execution:

```
CMD usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java -jar -Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,file:/opt/$APP/application.properties /opt/$APP/$APP-$VER.jar
```

And **it works again**. Both `another_sqs` and external mongo are loaded properly on "Try 4".

**My question is therefore:**

Why should I explicitly specify the `classpath:/application.proeprties`? Isn't `-Dspring.config.location=/opt/$APP/` or `-Dspring.config.location=file:/opt/$APP/application.properties` should be enough?

Comment: Did you try out the solution of my answer? Did you find any other solution for it?

Comment: @robertobatts - your solution seems to work, however I wanted a more comprehensive explanation for the behavior I described in the post.

Comment: Actually there is no other explanation, because that's just how Spring works. I updated my answer swith quotes from Spring documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `-Dspring.config.location=file:/opt/$APP/application.properties` you're overriding the default value of config.location with your application.properties. If you want to use another application.properties, but still using the default properties without declaring them you should use

```
-Dspring.config.additional-location=file:/opt/$APP/application.properties
```

In this way, config.location will still have the default value and you will load the external properties as an additional-location.

From the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> You can also refer to an explicit location by using the `spring.config.location` environment property (which is a comma-separated list of directory locations or file paths).
>   **When custom config locations are configured by `using spring.config.location`, they replace the default locations**
>
> Alternatively, when custom config locations are configured by using `spring.config.additional-location`, they are used in addition to the default locations.