# Is there a way to have several yml file for one project?

Tags: java, spring, yaml, cloud, profile

I want to sperate some security fields such as usernames or passwords from my main application.yml file . in fact I want 2 yml file in my project , one for main configs and other for security fields.
Is there any way to do that ?

*smaple:*

*Main yml file:*

```
spring:
     application:
      name: My project
  datasource:
    driverClassName:  com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    username: username
    password: password
    url: url
.....
```

security.yml

```
username: "username"
password: "password"
....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot and multiple external configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855795/spring-boot-and-multiple-external-configuration-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to specify profile specific .yml files. These are then activated by activating the corresponding profile.

So you can create `application-security.yml`

And in your main yml file add:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: 
      security
```