# Application ignores management.health.redis.enabled property

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-data-redis, health-check

I am using Springboot 3. Actuator version is 3.1.1. I have redis dependencies. However I do not want to check the redis health in my lower environment.
I tried setting management.health.redis.enabled=false to ignore the redis health check. However the property is ignored. Looks like my property file is not being picked up by my application during runtime on centos server even after attempting to set the config file location in a similar manner to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855795/spring-boot-and-multiple-external-configuration-files#:%7E:text=%2DDspring.config.location%3Dclasspath%3Ajob1.properties%2Cclasspath%3Ajob2.properties) example, this was not an issue in  previous version of springboot 2.7.12 but now with springboot 3.1.2 my properties is not picked up at runtime by my server environment

Comment: We were able to solve the issue by adding attribute SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION in the environment specific application.properties.