# Spring Boot Test : Property source with @Value not resolved

Tags: spring-boot, resourcebundle, spring-test-mvc

I've a problem in my JUNIT test with Spring boot : the @Value is not resolved.
Here the code :

**Spring boot config class :**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:/config/parametrage-environnement.properties",name="env")
public class ExternalRessourceConfiguration {

    //To resolve ${} in @Value
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }
}
```

**Class test :**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class ConnexionEbicsResourceIntTest {

@Test
@Transactional
public void createConnexionEbics() throws Exception {

            restConnexionEbicsMockMvc.perform(post("/api/connexionEbicss")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(connexionEbicsDTO)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
```

**Java ressource :**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ConnexionEbicsResource {

    @Value("${env['connexion.proxy.host']}")
    //@Value("${connexion.proxy.host}") 
    public String protocol;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/connexionEbicss",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<ConnexionEbicsDTO> createConnexionEbics( @RequestBody ConnexionEbicsDTO connexionEbicsDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save ConnexionEbics : {}", connexionEbicsDTO);
        String a = protocol;

}
```

In java ressource, when I run the test, "a" is null. The @Value was not resolved, why ? My spring boot configuration was ALL bootstraped.

The parametrage-environnement.properties file is located in both paths : src/main/resources/config and src/test/resources/config (copy/paste)

Answer (score 0):

1) Since my controller is mocked, I can't use spring injection directly present in the controller (**mocking annihilate Spring** !)

2) Syntax

```
@Value("${env['connexion.proxy.host']}")
```

is wrong because, env is supposed to be a spring bean (@Bean). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728000/value-not-resolved-when-using-propertysource-annotation-how-to-configure-prop)

So, With @PropertySource, we have to use @Value("${connexion.proxy.host}") syntax and don't forget the Resolver:

```
  //To resolve ${} in @Value
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }
```

3) To set the protocol in the controller class, I need to inject it from the Test class :

```
 @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ConnexionEbicsResource connexionEbicsResource = new ConnexionEbicsResource();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(connexionEbicsResource, "connexionEbicsService", connexionEbicsService);
        **ReflectionTestUtils.setField(connexionEbicsResource, "protocol", protocol);**
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(connexionEbicsResource, "connexionEbicsMapper", connexionEbicsMapper);
        this.restConnexionEbicsMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(connexionEbicsResource)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
            .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter).build();
    }
```

Having the loaded resource bundle in the test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@PropertySource(value="classpath:/config/parametrage-environnement.properties",name="env")
//@PropertySource("classpath:/config/parametrage-environnement.properties")
public class ConnexionEbicsResourceIntTest {
....
  @Value("${connexion.proxy.host}")
    public String protocol;
```

Thanks anyway

Comment: You could avoid the use of `ReflectionTestUtils` if you used constructor injection