# Set int value from properties file using spring

Tags: spring, properties

Trying to bind int value from properties file using spring

But everytime getting below exception :

```
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory]: 
Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"${rabitmq.server.host.connectionclosetimeout}\"
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"${rabitmq.server.host.connectionclosetimeout}\""}}
```

My properties file look like below :

```
rabitmq.server.host.connectionclosetimeout=30000
```

My Bean

```
@Value("${rabitmq.server.host.connectionclosetimeout}")
private int connectionCloseTimeOut;
```

Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config/service.properties")
public class RabbitMqConfiguration {

    @Value("${rabitmq.server.host.connectionclosetimeout}")
    private Integer connectionCloseTimeOut;

    /**
     * Establishing connection
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(host);
        connectionFactory.setCloseTimeout(connectionCloseTimeOut);
        return connectionFactory;
    }       

}
```

If I add below bean then its working fine. But I want to work without below bean

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

I have also tried with below method :

```
@Value("#{new Integer.parseInt('${rabitmq.server.host.connectionclosetimeout}')}")
private int connectionCloseTimeOut;
```

It's also not working.

Please suggest what is way to get it working.

Comment: *If I add below bean then its working fine. But I want to work without below bean*, No you can't, because you need a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in order to read dynamic properties.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty Have you tried annotating the class containing the connectionCloseTimeOut field with @Configuration?

Comment: Yes. its a configuration class, annotated with configuration

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty can you please share the complete class where you have the `connectionCloseTimeOut` field?

Comment: @MadhuBhat Added configuration class

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty please confirm if your query has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your SPEL isn't correct. This should work

```
@Value("#{ T(java.lang.Integer).parseInt('${rabitmq.server.host.connectionclosetimeout}') }")
private int connectionCloseTimeOut;
```

Try it out

Comment: Its throwing exception : Multiple markers at this line
 - Invalid character constant

Answer (score 0):

Below is from the doc of `PropertySource` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

> In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in  definitions or @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, one must register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. This happens automatically when using  in XML, but must be explicitly registered using a static @Bean method when using @Configuration classes.

So if you are using `@PropertySource`, to resolve the ${...} placeholders in `@Value` annotations you must register the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` either by

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

or by configuring the PSPC in the XML as below

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/service.properties" />
```

Please refer the spring JIRA ticket https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8539 and the SO thread [@Value not resolved when using @PropertySource annotation. How to configure PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728000/value-not-resolved-when-using-propertysource-annotation-how-to-configure-prop) for some more reference.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty Could you please confirm if this answer your query?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty but you had mentioned that it's working fine by using the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` Bean method right? If you use that static method in your configuration class, the property should get wired with the `@Value` annotation.

Comment: Its working in my Dev machine but not working UAT environment

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty you would need to check the difference between the Dev and UAT environment. This is beyond the scope of the question posted by you. Please accept the answer if it works in your Dev.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty could you please accept if this answered your question?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty if it works in your Dev env and not in your UAT env, you might need to check out the env differences.